# How should I configure the base href for Angular 2 when using Electron?

Tags: typescript, angular, electron, angular2-routing

I need to either set `<base>` in the HTML or `APP_BASE_HREF` during the bootstrap for Angular 2 to not throw exceptions. If I set either of these then `Electron`, thinking in terms of the file system, throws exceptions in `browser_adapter.ts` when trying to match a route:

> EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Cannot match any routes.
>   Current segment: 'C:'. Available routes: ['/dashboard', '/accounts'].

I tried using just the `HashLocationStrategy` mentioned in [this blog post](https://www.xplatform.rocks/2016/01/07/building-an-electron-app-using-angular2-beta0-in-typescript/), but Angular still complains about the base href not being set.

Comment: I don't know what electron is, but give this a try `<base href="./">` with a dot.

Comment: @Abdulrahman for someone who doesn't know what electron is that answer works for me. I took the angular2-tour-of-heros app and added an electron main.js but had to change to base = ./ to get it all working. Thanks.

Comment: Worked for me too - @Abdulrahman might I suggest you provide this as the correct answer? I'll gladly vote you up!

Answer (score 40):

Since the `href` attribute can take a relative path and thanks to @DavidC and @ChristianRondeau in the comments on the question for verifying, it should work like this:

```
<base href="./">
```

Comment: So anybody know why this isn't the default? None of the seeds use `./ ` for the base href. When would you ever want a hardcoded base path?

Comment: great for scenario where .war has SNAPSHOT-x.x.x and constantly changes! Many thanks!

Comment: Running into issues where lazy loaded routes cannot be resolved properly with this configuration

Comment: This doesn't work in many cases when a route is directly loaded from the address bar

Comment: This works for DOM path, but I am setting a background image in CSS. Here image file path note found and firing an error like 

GET file:///icon/png/icon.png net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: setting the base href to `./` breaks routing for using a direct url, to a path which is multiple levels deep. e.g. `http://localhost:4200/foo/bar`. And it will take you ages to find out, because the paths still work fine when navigated to from within your app. Keep this as `/`.

Comment: ... in addition to my previous comments. Perhaps we need 2 index.html files, one for running as electron, and one for when the website is used in a browser. In that case I guess you could indeed change your `/` to a `./`.

Comment: Does somebody found a better answer?

Answer (score 5):

In a clean way, You can ONLY customize your build command without editing the value of `<base href="/">` inside your `index.html` page

```
ng build --prod --base-href=./
```

Comment: note that --prod is now deprecated, but `--base-href=./` still works